# Invalid IP addresses in a university name server

Tags: dns

Does having some invalid IP in a university name server reduce its web rank? For example generating timeouts and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Search engines estimate static rank (i.e., query-independent rank) for sites and individual pages by a combination of [Pagerank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagerank) or similar algorithms that give higher rank to pages with lots of inbound links (i.e., pages that are linked to by many other pages) and [heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) that, e.g., may prefer `.gov` sites over `.biz` sites or which may prefer certain content, e.g., pages with titles only so many words long or with only so many links.  It's possible those heuristics might include downgrading a page that contains a lot of broken links.  But search engines do not consider whether a DNS somewhere has some bad entries.  Search engines only rank the pages they can find, not the ones they can't.

Comment: My university staff are really concerned about [webometrics](http://www.webometrics.info/). [Here](http://www.webometrics.info/en/detalles/iut.ac.ir) is ours. Does that follow the same rule?

Comment: Yes.  They've outlined how they calculate rank [here](http://www.webometrics.info/en/Methodology) and it matches what search engines do.  (Bear in mind that no one discloses all the ingredients of their secret sauce, only the general strategy they've employed.)

Comment: So they are pushing me over nothing!

Comment: Ranking algorithms try to estimate how a human would rank a page.  The better the algorithm or the better it's tuned (by training it on pages whose rank has been determined by human judges), the better it will mimic a human judge.  So if you'd like to make your site or your page rank near the top, the best general strategy is to do what it would take to make a human rank it highly (good content, good layout, meaningful URLs, useful links, etc.) and assume that most search engines should spot that.

Comment: Thank you, our home page has been designed and implemented by a fantastic web developer, all makes them 5th in Iran is their politics and lack of a good management. They've been bugging me over this issue in their DNS and they were assuming that this is the reason they are so poor in web ranks. Our faculty web pages are also unified and in a great shape, all done by the students themselves.

Comment: Yes, I just quickly browsed [your site](http://www.iut.ac.ir/).  It's very attractively laid out.  If your DNS has errors that are breaking any links on your pages, that should of course be fixed.  But other outdated and other junk entries in your DNS will have no effect on what webometrics sees when they spider your site to develop their estimate of rank.